# Node Printing 'undefined' For BaseObject.Prototype in Shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, output, prototypal-inheritance

I've been googling around for this, and for the life of me I can't seem to find a satisfactory answer. I realize I'm either doing something wrong with Node, or being completely unaware of how prototypical inheritance works, but for me this is just driving me crazy not knowing why, so I would appreciate any feedback to help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

I have three classes. These classes can do whatever, but they'll have the names for the sake of this discussion.

- Mammal.js
- Human.js
- test.js

Mammal is the base class, Human is the sub-class, and test is the class that executes the code. Now, I know there are various ways to extend another object. whether that's by using Object.create(), or the constructor configuration. In this instance I am using a constructor function to create the new objects, and I am pointing the prototypes of the sub-classes directly to the object that it's inheriting from. So the subclasses by default should have to go up the prototype chain to the object that it's inheriting from if it can't find the method in the sub-class.

Now when I do this it works... Sort of? I can call one of the functions and it will act as if it's been overridden, but when I try to inspect the object, or the prototype or any information via console.log() in node, I get virtually nothing. It's terribly confusing to me and I'd love help to get clarification on why that is.

Below are the classes and the output I'm using.

## Mammal.js

```
module.exports = (function() {
    function Mammal() {
        // do nothing
    }

    Mammal.prototype = {};

    Mammal.prototype.initialize = function initialize() {
        throw Error(this.type() + ' has extended the "Mammal" class without overriding the "type" function. Please assign this function correctly in the new sub-class.');
    };
    Mammal.prototype.speak = function speak() {
        // Mammal.speak.call(this);
        console.log('I am a ' + this.type() + '.');
    };
    Mammal.prototype.type = function type() {
        throw Error('A sub-object has extended the "Mammal" class without overriding the "type" function. Please assign this function correctly in the new sub-class.');
    };
    Mammal.prototype.printDebug = function printDebug() {
        console.log(this.type() + " prototype: " + this.prototype);
    };

    return Mammal;
})();
```

## Human.js

```
var Mammal = require('./Mammal');

module.exports = (function() {
    function Human() {
        // Call to super
        Mammal.constructor.call(this);
    };

    Human.prototype = new Mammal();

    Human.prototype.initialize = function initialize() {
        // do something
    };
    Human.prototype.type = function type() {
        return "Human";
    };

    return Human;
})();
```

## test.js

```
var Human = require('./Human');
var human = new Human();
console.log("------------------------")
console.log("Object Inspection")
console.log("------------------------")
console.log(human);
console.log("------------------------")
console.log("Prototype Inspection")
console.log("------------------------")
console.log(human.prototype);
console.log("------------------------")
console.log("Stringify Inspection")
console.log("------------------------")
console.log(JSON.stringify(human.prototype));
console.log("------------------------")
console.log("Object printDebug")
console.log("------------------------")
human.printDebug();
console.log("------------------------")
console.log("Object printDebug")
console.log("------------------------")
console.log(human.type());
console.log("------------------------")
console.log("Speak")
console.log("------------------------")
human.speak();
```

## Output

```
------------------------
Object Inspection
------------------------
{}
------------------------
Prototype Inspection
------------------------
undefined
------------------------
Stringify Inspection
------------------------
undefined
------------------------
Object printDebug
------------------------
Human prototype: undefined
------------------------
Object printDebug
------------------------
Human
------------------------
Speak
------------------------
I am a Human.
```

My expectation is that the human.prototype would point to something. In particular the Mammal object that was declared. As well as it not outputting the human object as an empty set of brackets, when it really has the methods from the Mammal class that it's "extending" from. Wouldn't it show the prototype references? It's obvious that it has some methods in its prototype chain because it's executing the speak command without any issues.

So what am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 0):

Ah. Someone has clarified the issue for me.  I was conflating the human.prototype property with the _ *prototype* _ property of an object. The latter is the reference that will be traversed when it cannot find the method in the current object. Because of that it makes sense why it was returning undefined. Because human.prototype is totally separate from human._ *prototype* _.  The suggested solution for this was also to use, Object.getPrototypeOf(object), except that won't work in older opera browsers, from what MDN says. So, heads up!